# c++ wrapper class efficiency

Tags: c++, performance, subclass, wrapper

I am coding some performance-sensitive tool in C++. `int`, `long` and pointers to them are used extensively for widely different purposes. I would like to provide some separation so that the code is easier to understand. I am not really concerned about bug prevention (e.g. I am making everything global), so separation of concerns in this case is more of a, say, aesthetical issue.

I would like to make subclasses of built-in types. Of course, just changing the name is easy with a typedef. However, I would also like to be able to add new methods. Say, I want to make a "subclass", or something that looks like it, `cell` of `int*`. What comes to my head is to use a wrapper for `int*`, then subclass it.

1) How can I reasonably define a wrapper for `int*` without needing to redefine almost every operator that can be applied to `int*`? Or else, is there any library that already defines one? I am trying to stick to the standard library, but any MIT license-compatible library would do.

2) Is there an overhead of using such a wrapper (or the subclass, for that matter) over directly using an `int*`? I don't plan to use polymorphism, so no virtual functions involved. It's really a matter of readability.

Comment: Use the implicit conversion operator to unbox `int*`

Comment: Honestly, your idea does not sound right. If you want to improve readability, than you would better encapsulate some parts of code in separate functions and/or classes that perform all the necessary actions without the need to wrap `int*`. This way you will form some kind of high-level API, that is easy to use and read.

Comment: Thanks for your input @InnokentiyAlaytsev . This is in fact what the current state of the code is. Due to `int*` being used for many different things, it  is still very hard to follow what is going on. This code is meant not only to be efficient, but also to be readily understood, hence the request. If it is impossible to do so without harming efficiency, then I'll leave it as is.

Comment: @JakeFreeman , I had the impression that using so many implicit conversions would have a significant overhead, since it would be used pretty much everywhere at runtime. Are standard compilers able to optimize this away?

Comment: @Jaeya, modern compilers may try to inline all those invocations. However, if there is some logic beside returning or setting value the resulting code may be slower than the original.

Comment: How about templates? Define a wrapper, once, for `T` that redefines almost every operator. Then `typedef wrapper<int> Int; typedef wrapper<int*> PInt; class Cell: public wrapper<int*>`, etc

Comment: what about `std::unique_ptr<int>`? (shared_ptr, weak_ptr also available) Just as a suggestion for an already existing wrapper of int*.

Comment: I think you would save so much grief if you just preferred nonmember functions, like `round(x), instead of trying to create a wrapper class with those functions as methods. Then you don't have to worry about defining operators or anything like that, and you don't have to worry about your classes going out of style.

Comment: As for wrapper overhead, there's typically none/close as long as you don't introduce dynamic dispatch with virtual functions (otherwise the cost is enormously expensive from a relative standpoint compared to a plain old `int*`). The optimizer is great at squashing away such overhead for the most part or else no one would have picked up C++. But I still think the temptation to wrap here could end up being something you regret down the line. If, instead, you write functions that accept an `int*` as a parameter to clarify intentions, that's not nearly as intrusive as designing a new data type.